# Error with PHP and MySQL. Some code gets executed and error message displayed

Tags: php, mysql

My system goes like this:
After registering in the MySQL database and a verification message is sent to an email, there is a link in that message that directs the user to a page called **activate.php**. Here comes the error:

```
<?php    
$query = "SELECT active FROM users WHERE id='";
$query .= $_SESSION['id'];
$query .= "' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ( $row['active'] == 'false' ) {

    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `active`='true' WHERE `id`='";
    $query .= $_SESSION['id'];
    $query .= "' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    **//THE END**
    if ( $result ) header("diary.php");
    else echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Activation Failed! Server error!.');</script>";

} else {
    header("diary.php");
}
?>
```

for the end section written as a comment,all of the previous code gets executed successfully and does update the table in the MySQL database. The rest of the code doesn't get executed at all and I always get an error message at the same time the code is executed.
The error message is:
[Error message relating to a server error although some of the code gets executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndjvN.png)

I really searched for that error a lot but nothing useful. I already made sure that the syntax has no errors.

Note: I've the link to the database working but didn't mention it for security issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is the page user gets to see after he/she clicks on a link received in mail, then you can't expect that the session is still alive. I think the whole root cause of this issue is this `$_SESSION['id']`. First check whether session is expired or not. Do `echo $_SESSION['id'];` and see if you get any value or not.

Comment: And also remove line `**//THE END**`, it will give you this `unexpected '' (T_POW)` syntax error.

Comment: I'm just adding this    **//THE END** to make it clear which part I'am pointing for and it isn't in the actual code.

Comment: Look at your code, you've added this line, `**//THE END**`. `//**THE END**` is fine, but this `**//THE END**` will give syntax error.

Comment: I've this    session_start();     in my actual code at the top but forgot to paste it here. I also tested your method of echoing the session variable and it really exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. The header syntax should be as follows:

```
    header("Location:diary.php");
```

Thanks everyone. It's now working great!